# Call PHP with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

I always seem to be having questions and messing up.  University taught us nothing about PHP and I want to use it to send an email.  Could anyone help?  I am using JavaScript to validate and then PHP to send the form.  Here's what I have.

PHP:

```
<?php

$to = 'jd20032007@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'Voice4Autism Inquiry';

$FirstName = $_POST['fname'];
$LastName = $_POST['lname'];
$eMail = $_POST['email'];

$message = <<<EMAIL

Hi!<br /><br/>

My name is $FirstName $LastName.  I am interseted in your newsletter from Voice4Autism.  Please add $eMail to your listserve.<br /><br />

Thank you,<br />
$FirstName $LastName

EMAIL;

$header = "From: $eMail\r\n";
$header = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";


mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

?>
```

HTML/JavaScript

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script>
    function checkforblank() {
        var errormessage = "";

        if (document.getElementById('fname').value ==""){
            errormessage += "enter your first name \n";
        }
        if (document.getElementById('lname').value ==""){
            errormessage += "enter your last name \n";
        }
        if (document.getElementById('email').value ==""){
            errormessage += "enter your email \n";
        }
        if (document.getElementById('confirmEmail').value ==""){
            errormessage += "confirm your email \n";
        }

        if (errormessage != ""){
            alert(errormessage);
            return false;
        } else return true;
    }

    function verifyEmail() {
        var status = false;     
        var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

        if (document.myForm.email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
                  alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        }


        if (document.getElementById('email').value == document.getElementById('confirmEmail').value) {
            alert("Thank you for your interest!");
                status = true;            
        } else {
            alert("Email addresses do not match.  Please retype them to make sure they are the same.");
        }

        return status;
    }

    function confirmEmailAddresses(){
        if (checkforblank() == true) {
            if (verifyEmail() == true) {
                document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            }
        } 
    }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

<div id="content">
<form name="myForm" action="#" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="">
<table width="377" height="96">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">First Name:</td>
    <td><label for="FirstName"></label>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">Last Name:</td>
    <td><label for="LastName"></label>
      <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">E-mail:</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">Confirm E-mail:</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="confirmEmail" id="confirmEmail"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Send" onClick="confirmEmailAddresses()"><input type="reset" value="Reset Form">

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript and HTML does work!!!

Comment: `The JavaScript and HTML does work!!!` what does it mean?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php   .This could help you

Comment: Use Ajax, after validating send the request using Ajax..There you can use php mail function.

Comment: @wr02 Ajax is not needed here.

Comment: You should also vaidate and sanitize the data being sent server side. Don't rely on the client side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is absolutely not needed here, unless you want the page to persist. Just set the form `action` to the file that will receive the form data and mail it.

```
<form name="myForm" action="mailer.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="">
```

Set the form method to POST. It's better. Now in your `mailer.php` (you can name it whatever, just make sure to use the correct name for action) file handle the `$_POST` array to get the form data. Note that the page will refresh, you can use a redirect to a thank you page after form submission.

Change the button to this:

```
<input type="submit" name="send_mail" value="Send" onClick="confirmEmailAddresses()">
```

Your PHP file can be something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST['send_mail']) && $_POST['send_mail'] == 'Send'){
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $confirm_email = $_POST['confirmEmail'];

        //Additional validation here
        //Use the mail function to send the email

        //If mail sent, redirect to a thank you/confirmation page
    }
}
?>
```

Check the [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) documentation for working examples.

Comment: This looks like it would work!  It looks good!  I'm trying to keep it to one page for now.  Would the mail function go in here?

Comment: Yep it would. I've added in appropriate comments.

Comment: Alright!  I'm getting emails, but every time I visit or refresh the page...so close!

Comment: Yes, a page refresh will cause the code to run. But seems strange that visiting the page too does that. Wait, let me edit.

Comment: Check now, you need to use a `submit`.

Comment: Great!  I changed "button" to "submit" but even when I visit the page initially, there is an email fired out.

EDIT:  When I did that, not all my code was validated when the emails formatting is mismatched if the 'button' is changed to 'submit'

Answer (score 0):

for mail you can [check here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

$to is to whiche email address email should sent

$subject is just brief description of mail

$message is your message

$header is header content type like MIME

Comment: Thank you!  I added it to the code above and checked it out on the test server I'm using, but it's still not working.

Comment: for checking purpose change $message="test mail";...check this once

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure all of your code works. But one thing I notice is you need to provide target url(php file in this case) in action="" attribute that tells the browser where to send the captured data for handling.

```
<form name="myForm" action="#" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="">
```

to

```
<form name="myForm" action="your_php_program.php" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="">
```

Answer (score -2):

I would use AJAX.
But first make sure your Webserver supports mailing with PHP. You can check this using phpinfo()
But it seems like your PHP Script isn't sending a mail() at all...

Comment: I'm extremely new to this so AJAX is a bit over my head.  My server does support PHP.

Comment: Jap, but AJAX is very easy to learn. You could use a Javascript function in which you can put $.("#ElementID").load("phpfile.php"); But first you need to implement the Json Library ;)